# Sending a HTTP POST REQUEST with image and text

Tags: javascript, express, http, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I send an image along with a text in VueJs to my backend ExpressJs?

Right now, what I did was create two http post request

**NOTE** this.albumName and this.albumDesc are just text and the formData is an image.

```
createAlbum() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      for (let file of Array.from(this.myAlbumImages)) {
        formData.append("files", file);
      }

      if (this.albumName) {
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:9001/image/album", {
            ALBUM: this.albumName,
            DESCRIPTION: this.albumDesc
          })
          .then(resp => console.log(resp))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        setTimeout(function() {
          axios
            .post("http://localhost:9001/image/album", formData)
            .then(resp => console.log(resp))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }, 3000);

        this.albumName = "";
        this.albumDesc = "";
      } else {
        alert("Please fill the above form.");
      }
    },
```

and here is my Backend.

This creates the folder based on the passed data and it also creates a named **undefined** folder

```
router.post('/album', (req, res) => {
let sql = "INSERT INTO GALLERY SET ALBUM = ?, DESCRIPTION = ?";
let body = [req.body.ALBUM, req.body.DESCRIPTION]
myDB.query(sql, body, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        let directory = `C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/adminbackend/public/${req.body.ALBUM}`;
        fse.mkdirp(directory, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(directory);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I think this is because of NodeJS is Asynchronous that's why it creates the undefined folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for behavior you see is you are sending two different requests to the same route. 1st includes ALBUM and DESCRIPTION form field values, but not the files. Second (inside `setTimeout`) will contain just files and no other fields, so referencing them like `req.body.ALBUM` will return `undefined`

You can send all data (text fields and files) in one request. Just do this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
for (let file of Array.from(this.myAlbumImages)) {
  formData.append("files", file);
}
formData.append("ALBUM", this.albumName);
formData.append("DESCRIPTION", this.albumDesc);
axios.post("http://localhost:9001/image/album", formData)
     .then(resp => console.log(resp))
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) always uses content type [multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean). To parse it on server side you need Express middleware that parses multipart forms, and gives you access to both fields and image/s. For example [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)...

Answer (score 0):

for the first part the client may can help you this link [How to post image with fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284011/how-to-post-image-with-fetch)

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#your-file-input') ;
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      // If you add this, upload won't work
      // headers: {
      //   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      // }
    };

    fetch('your-upload-url', options);
```

and for the seerver part cant help you this link 
[Node Express sending image files as API response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515699/node-express-sending-image-files-as-api-response)

```
app.get('/report/:chart_id/:user_id', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

and oficial documentation about this 
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile